# Как создать File?

Tags: android

Я пытаюсь создать файл, с пдф, которое пришло в response. 
Файл не создаётся и адаптер указывает на null reference

Листинг:

```
  StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
  AppConfig.URL_PDF, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        hideDialog();
                                try {
                                    Log.d(TAG2, "Подключаюсь к Базе " + 
         response.toString());
      // Log.d(TAG3, "HELLO!");
      // JSONObject jObj = new     JSONObject(response);


     File file = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(),"my.pdf");
     Toast.makeText(getContext(),"hello!!!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     FileOutputStream outputStream =  getContext().openFileOutput("my.pdf",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                    outputStream.write(response.getBytes());
      outputStream.close();

     adapter = new PDFPagerAdapter(getContext(),file.getAbsolutePath());

   remotePDFViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
   //remotePDFViewPager = new RemotePDFViewPager(getContext(), , listener);

   remotePDFViewPager.setId(R.id.pdfViewPager);
   updateLayout();
         } catch (Exception e) {

             e.printStackTrace();
      }



}
```

Любой совет

Comment: Код нужно вставлять текстом, а не изображением. Мало у кого есть желание вглядываться в мутный текст.

Comment: пермишн за запись файла предоставили?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FileOutputStream  stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
try {
   stream.write( response.toString().getBytes() );
   stream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```